# Add right click sharing to Ubuntu Server 13.10 running Gnome-shell 3.8?

Tags: networking, server, gnome, samba, file-sharing

New to Ubuntu but some limited experience with other distros.  I was trying out Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS and I was able to right click a folder and share it on my home network.  I wasn't crazy about the performance of the machine so, in an effort to get a lighter/stripped down install, I wiped it and installed Ubuntu Server 13.10 and gnome-shell 3.8 (and a bunch of other things based on various how-to web pages to try to get the "right click > share" functionality back).  I remembered that I had to install samba when I was using 12.04 so I installed that through synaptic.  I did manage to get the personal file sharing preferences window to let me share files over the network but if I'm not mistaken, that only shares the `~/Public` folder (and I've yet to test it).  Is it possible to get "right click > share" functionality in this configuration and if so how?  Thanks